# How to implement artifact storage in gitlab CI via artifactory

Tags: gitlab-ci, artifactory, artifacts

I am working with a Gitlab 11 instance, which is configured not to offer the artifact service to transparently pass artifacts between build stages. I have a number of build definitions that I need to port. I have an artifactory server available and I can create custom repository layouts on it.

Here is the question:

**How can I *best* replace the artifact storage in Gitlab with an externalisation and reload from artifactory?**